# Unable to Watermark an Uploaded Video Using protonemedia / laravel-ffmpeg

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I am trying to watermark a video to prevent users from downloading the original video.

Below is my code for uploading a video, followed by watermarking it:

```
public function watermarkpost(Request $request)
{

    if ($file = $request->file('watermark')) 
    {      
       $name = time().str_replace(' ', '', $file->getClientOriginalName());
       $file->move('assets/images/products',$name);           
    }
        FFMpeg::open(asset('assets/images/products/'.$name))->addWatermark(function(WatermarkFactory $watermark) {
            $watermark
            ->open(asset('assets/images/1571567292logo.png') )
            ->right(25)
            ->bottom(25);
        });
   
    // return asset('assets/images/products/'.$name);
}
```

The error:

```
Alchemy\\BinaryDriver\\Exception\\ExecutableNotFoundException(code: 0): Executable not found, proposed : ffmpeg at F:\\xampp\\htdocs\\GeniusCart\\project\\vendor\\alchemy\\binary-driver\\src\\Alchemy\\BinaryDriver\\AbstractBinary.php:159)
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

### Installation

You need to install **ffmpeg** and **ffprobe** on your system.
You can download the required release of these based on your os from [this url](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

### Configuration

After installing them, you should give the path to their executive binaries. Laravel ffmpeg provides a config for this purpose. Give it the proper address to the ffmpeg and ffprobe binaries in your .env file.

```
FFMPEG_BINARIES=
FFPROBE_BINARIES=
```